# Shell subtract one alphabet letter from current letter

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

I have a file called "current_letter.txt" which displays today's letter  (A-K)

```
cat current_letter.txt
C
```

Each day the letter increments by one letter (Yesterday's letter would have been "B" Tomorrow's letter will be "D"

How can I put yesterdays letter into a variable?

```
Example:
A=K
B=A
C=B
D=C
E=D
F=E
G=F
H=G
I=H
J=I
K=J
```

I'm trying to put yesterday's letter into a variable like

```
yesterdays_letter=`cat current_letter.txt - 1`
```

So it uses a - k then repeats itself

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `tr` for all your Caesar cipher needs:

```
#!/bin/bash
for c in {A..Z}
do
  b=$(printf '%s' "$c" | tr 'B-ZA' 'A-Z')
  echo "One letter before $c is $b"
done
```

This outputs:

```
One letter before A is Z
One letter before B is A
One letter before C is B
One letter before D is C
(etc)
```

Answer (score 0):

<s>The example section you give makes no sense, is that a file's content?</s>

here is the solution:

```
a='ABCDEFGHIJK';
v=$(cat current_letter.txt);
if [ "$v" = 'A' ]; then 
  var='K'; 
else 
  var=${a[$(($(expr index $a $v)-2))]};
fi;
echo $var;
```

Comment: Hi @ddwolf No the example section means if I "cat current_letter.txt" and the output is "B" i want the variable to be "A" or if "cat current_letter.txt" and the output is "A" I want the variable to be "K" so the example section just represents what i want the letter to be